# Proper use of HashSet.contains()?

Tags: java, contains, hashset

I'm attempting to generate a maze using a version of Kruskal's algorithm. I need to check if some coordinates (in an int[] array, eg [1, 5]) are in an existing set.

Here is a copy of the part of the code;

```
// find sets containing cells to be joined
for (HashSet<int[]> h : cells) {
    if (h.contains(new int[]{x, y - 2})) {
        set1 = h;
    }
}
```

The issue is that the if statement is never true, but I'm 99.9% sure it should be true at least once.

Am I using HashSet.contains() wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Am I using HashSet.contains() wrong?

Well, you have an expectation which is wrong, but it's more about arrays than about `HashSet`. Arrays in Java don't implement `equals` and `hashCode` in the way it looks like you're expecting them to. They effectively exhibit reference equality behaviour. For example:

```java
int[] array1 = { 1 };
int[] array2 = { 1 };
System.out.println(array1.equals(array1)); // true - same reference
System.out.println(array1.equals(array2)); // false - different reference
```

Rather than using an `int[]` for coordinates, I'd suggest creating a `Coordinate` class with `x` and `y` fields. If that `Coordinate` class then overrides `equals` and `hashCode` appropriately, *then* using `HashSet` will work. (Although I'd advise creating the object you're looking for *outside* the loop rather than in each iteration.)

Answer (score 0):

`HashSet` contains() Method in Java
util. `HashSet` `contains()` method is used to check whether a specific element is present in the HashSet or not. So basically it is used to check if a Set contains any particular element.

Comment: more info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this will help:

```
Stream.generate(() -> new int[] { 1, 2 }.hashCode()).limit(3).forEach(System.out::println);
```

notice we're printing the hashcode of `[1, 2]` three times but we get three unique values. That is because each `new int[]` has a different `hashCode()`. Create a custom type, override `hashCode` and add **that** to your `HashSet`. Something like

```
public class Cell {
    private final int x, y;

    public Cell(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 13 ^ x ^ y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            return false;
        } else if (this == o) {
            return true;
        } else if (o instanceof Cell) {
            Cell c = (Cell) o;
            return this.x == c.x && this.y == c.y;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would advise making the `Cell` (or `Coordinate`) class immutable. Aside from anything else, mutating the object in a hashcode-affecting way after it's been added to a `HashSet` will break the expectations of `HashSet`.